# Error "TypeError: $(...).children is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to select a certain DOM element with jQuery.

The HTML content:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <nav id="nav" class="navigator">
      <h1>Nav Header</h1>

      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-item"><a >Item #1</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item active"><a href="#2">Item #2</a></li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to select Item #1. I used

```
$('.nav-list').children()
```

I got

> TypeError: $(...).children is not a function

What's wrong here?

Comment: Did you forget to include jQuery?

Comment: @Scimonster I tried through JS console in Chrome

Comment: The Chrome JS console includes a `$()` function by default, but it is not jQuery.

Comment: You need to include jQuery.... https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: @Hellolad: jQuery is not included for you in the console. `$` is defined to be `document.getElementById` there, by default.

Comment: What does `$ === jQuery` return in your console?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: @Hellolad You clearly have a problem while loading jQuery. Is that your full code? What does the network tab said about the loading on jQuery?

Comment: Are you loading this page from a web server, or directly from your file system?

Comment: @JLRishe directly from file system

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon you are totally right. I see no js code loaded. That is not the full code. my code includes a loading of pic from remote server which succeeded.

Comment: Try using `http` : `<script src="http://ajax.goog...`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to include jQuery in your page.

Most browsers nowadays include a `$()` function in their console by default for easy element selection, but this simply maps to `document.getElementById()`.

The value returned will not have a `.children()` method.

Additionally, if you load an HTML page directly from your file system, you need to include the `http://` for CDN script URLs. Otherwise, your browser will try to find the .js file on your local system.

Comment: I do have jQuery lib included, just forget to publish it

Answer (score 5):

In my case the problem was fixed by replacing '.children()' with 'children'.

I got an array of children as a result.

Comment: Then you weren't actually using jQuery at all. Or if you did, you weren't operating on a jQuery wrapped element/collection. The reason it worked as non-function call is that you accessed [the vanilla DOM `Element.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children), instead of [jQuery's `.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) which is *always* a function.

Answer (score 4):

Going from the fact that $ doesn't refer to jQuery in the browser's console I found a way to change this for the current session within Google Chrome. I just pasted the JavaScript source from this github page into the console:

[use jQuery in Chrome javascript console](https://gist.github.com/takkyuuplayer/5876999)

The code for future reference:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
jQuery.noConflict();
```

After that I could

```
$("html").children()
```